# Migrating Transformer from cucumber 2 to cucumber 7

Tags: java, migration, cucumber

I have a task here to upgrade from cucumber 2 to 7 and I managed to find everything but not how to migrate `Transformer` and `@Transform` code like bellow one:

```
import cucumber.api.Transformer;
import cucumber.runtime.java.guice.ScenarioScoped;
import java.util.Optional;

public class OptionalStringTransformer extends Transformer<Optional<String>> {
    @Override
    public Optional<String> transform(String s) {
        return Optional.ofNullable(s);
    }
}

@ScenarioScoped
public class StepDefinitions {
    @And("^Some ?(not)? step?$")
    public void someStep(@Transform(OptionalStringTransformer.class) Optional<String> example){
        // Step code
    }
}
```

Anyone know how to do it?

Comment: Did you try checking the Cucumber documentation? It's most likely mentioned in one of the release note documents in any of the 5 (!) major versions you skipped.

Comment: They removed it on 3 and there is just a note saying that they are not providing a migration guide :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By now it is possible to use `Optional<String>` without any custom code.

```java
  @And("^Some ?(not)? step?$")
  public void someStep(Optional<String> example){
    System.out.println(example);
  }
```

Will print either `Optional.empty` or `Optional[not]`.

Answer (score 1):

The [3.0 release post](https://cucumber.io/blog/open-source/announcing-cucumber-jvm-3-0-0/) says:

> (...) @Transformer (...) from XStream will no longer work. These must be replaced by DataTableType or ParameterType

In other words, you'll have to replace that feature with something else. It's just no longer supported by Cucumber.